# Set default version of Python in ArcGIS to 64-bit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3, arcgis-10.6, anaconda

This is the output from Python terminal within `ArcMap 10.6.1` for Windows 10:

```
>>> import sys, numpy, matplotlib
>>> print(sys.version, numpy.__version__, matplotlib.__version__)
('2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]', '1.9.3', '1.5.2')
```

How can I set the default Python version to 64-bit? I don't want to change the System Environment Variables as it would probably mess up with the other `Python 3.6` from `Anaconda3` 64-bit installed on the same PC.

Here is my `Python27` folder structure

[image]

Comment: I doubt this is possible since Arc 10.x is a 32-bit application and the Python interpreter available in the console is "embedded".

Comment: If you require a 64-bit Python interpreter from ArcGIS Desktop, using ArcGIS Pro is going to be your solution.  There is a 64-bit Background Geoprocessing package for ArcMap, but that only applies when background geoprocessing is enabled.

Comment: @Vince: unfortunately I don't have access to ArcGIS Pro license. Thanks!

Comment: @Tung I would double-check on that - it seems it is fairly typical that you get a "free" Pro license with any ArcMap license.

Comment: @PhilippNagel: cool. I'll check with our local admin. Thanks!

Comment: You can run ArcGIS from a batch file, overwriting system variables for only *that single instance*, this will not affect any other software... similar to the OSGeo shell. Other benefits include being able to launch ArcMap with an elevated priority, changing the TEMP and TMP directory and specifying processor affinity.